# PHP - Loop by index

Tags: php, arrays, loops, indexing

I use PHP and have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [34] => Array
    (
        [slug] => my_slug
        [title] => my_title
    )
    [33] => Array
    (
        [slug] => my_slug2
        [title] => my_title2
    )
)
```

I also need to loop out the sets, key 34 with values and key 33 with values. I could loop them out with a foreach but in my case I can't use a foreach loop.

**Problem - Loop by index?**

Because I can't use a foreach loop in my case I need to come up with something where I can loop them by index.

**My own thoughts**

if I could get the array keys by index it would be fine. Is it possible, how?

```
<?php print_r( $my_array[index][0] ); ?>
<?php print_r( $my_array[index][1] ); ?>
```

**Reasons**

The reason why I can't use a foreach is that I am depending on a counter. If the counter says 3 it wants to get the fourth key (arrays starts with 0).

**Example 1**

```
$counter = 1;
```

Then it should return the contents of [33] because it's on the index 1.

**Example 2**

```
$counter = 0;
```

Then it should return the contents of [34] because it's on the index 0.

Comment: I don't get what your problem is exactly..

Comment: `$my_array[$counter]['slug']` ?

Comment: Yes, you can get the array keys with `array_keys` php function.

Comment: Why not use an iterating for loop? `for ($i = 0, $count = count$(my_array); $i < $count; $i++ { // do something with $my_array[$i] }`

Comment: @EM-Creations I added 2 examples.

Comment: If he can't use a foreach then its a uni project or something like that where the limitations are "do this without using this easy to do it function" they do it all the time though I'm not sure what the purpose of teaching bad coding habits is.  Use a while or a do while or a for loop instead. you're not using the foreach as specified you're just using another loop method that does EXACTLY the same anyway :) (at least in this case it will)

Comment: So maybe you can work with some arithmetic combination like `$array[34-$counter]`

Comment: why use a counter like that way at all you can do as @shanethehat posted which will just itterate over a variable length parent array and allow you to return the sub array which you can then either itterate over again or pull out statis keys if you know them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Get the keys out of the array with `array_keys` and then use to counter to find the index you want to iterate over.  You can then use a simple foreach loop to iterate over the sub array.

```
$keys     = array_keys($array);
$index    = $keys[$counter];
$subArray = $array[$index];
foreach($subArray as $key => $value) {
    // do stuff
}
```

### Explanation

For the array you gave in the example `array_keys($array)` returns

```
array(
    0 => 34,
    1 => 33
);
```

So we can use counter on this new array to figure out the index of in the actual array we want to iterate over.

```
$index = $keys[$counter];
```

So if `$counter = 0` then `$index` is now `34`.  Now it's simple enough to use `$index` on the original array to get the sub array we want to iterate over.

```
$subArray = $array[$index];
```

In this example with `$counter` being `0` the variable `$subArray` now holds

```
array(
    'slug'  => 'my_slug'
    'title' => 'my_title'
);
```

## Not using foreach

Its fairly simple to adapt this answer to work without a `foreach` loop.  Read the [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) documentation and think about how that function could allow other types of loops to iterate over arrays with string keys.

## References

[array_keys documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 1):

> The reason why I can't use a foreach is that I am depending on a counter. If the counter says 3 it wants to get the fourth key (arrays starts with 0).

No problem:

```
var_dump($array[array_keys($array)[3]]);
```

(This requires PHP 5.4 because of the array dereferencing syntax)

*For PHP 5.3 or earlier:*

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
var_dump($array[$keys[3]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is what you are looking for...

```
$counter = 3; // for example
$keys = array_keys($my_array);
$needed_entry = $keys[ $counter ];

print_r( $my_array[ $needed_entry ] );
```